# How do I write a program that can designate consecutive numbers in vertical patterns in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that can designate 1,2,3,4,5,....until a certain number in a vertical pattern in a two-dimensional array, and at the same time, avoid the one that is 0.

So, the initial array may be like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
```

And I want the `1`s to become numbers from 1 to 5 (which is the "certain number" I mentioned at the beginning of the question), and it should be like this:

```
1 5 3 5 1
2 0 0 1 2
3 1 0 0 3
4 2 4 0 0
```

My idea is to write another one-dimensional array to memorize the sequence that will be the input as a two-dimensional array. And after that, if the number in the two-dimensional array is not 0, we let the number change into the number of the sequence.

Here is how I wrote it:

```c
int a[4][5] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
int sequence[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(a[i][j] == 1){
            a[i][j] = sequence[i];
        }
    }
}
    
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And the output will be like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 0 0 2 2
3 3 0 0 3
4 4 4 0 0
```

I might have an idea of what happened to the code because the sequence array index runs with the array index. So, every time it runs back to 0, the sequence array will set back to 0 as well.

Therefore, I tried to get another variable as the sequence array's index. The idea is that when the number of the two-dimensional array is 1, the variable will be plus 1.
And this is how I wrote:

```
int a[4][5] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
int sequence[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    int z = -1;
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(a[i][j] == 1){
            z ++;
            a[i][j] = sequence[z];  
        }
    }
}
    
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

But the output will be like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 0 0 2 3
1 2 0 0 3
1 2 3 0 0
```

I can't think of any other way to write this code. How can I write this code correctly? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there, the bug is in how you handle 'z' you reset it to the beginning of the sequence at every column (when you assign it -1).

Here is a fixed version with some improvements (mainly variable naming) for you to learn from.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // give your constant values readable names 
    // I use std::size_t since indices in arrays cannot be < 0
    const std::size_t columns{ 5ul };
    const std::size_t rows{ 4ul };
    const std::size_t sequence_length{ 5ul };


    int values[rows][columns] = { {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0} };
    int sequence[sequence_length] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // you will start at this index into your sequence
    std::size_t sequence_index{ 0ul };

    // Move over columns first, again here use readable names
    // for column so you document in code what your code is doing.
    for (std::size_t column = 0; column < columns; ++column)
    {
        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        {
            // now check if we encounter a one, this needs to be replaced
            if (values[row][column] == 1)
            {
                // replace by number from sequence
                values[row][column] = sequence[sequence_index];

                // then move to next sequence, and use modulo sequence length keep values within range of the sequence
                sequence_index = (sequence_index + 1) % sequence_length;
            }
        }
    }

    // for output, I use a range based for loop
    // these are prefered if you can use them to avoid
    // going out of bounds of your arrays.
    for (const auto& row : values)
    {
        for (const auto& value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```